# Holding each multi line match using sed or awk or any commands

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a pattern which is spread across multiple lines, and there are many like this. I need to further process on every such mutli line pattern match found.

Below command is the one I am trying:

```
cat file_with_match | grep -Pv '^$' | sed -nre '/Pure delay/I,/END OF PATH/Ip'
```

This gives all the matches. I want to manipulate each of those and further process.

My file is something like below:

Pure delay path #308 ,

0.003  0.003  0.032  0.003  (F) 0.003 af mclk

0.019  0.022  0.006  0.001  (F) 0.022 af mclk

END OF PATH

Pure delay path #309,

0.003  0.003  0.032  0.003  (F) 0.003 af mclk

0.019  0.022  0.006  0.001  (F) 0.022 af mclk

END OF PATH

This is just for explanation. I will then need to add up all the first column in each of those mutli line matches and then print it along with the #id

Not finding how to handle this. Any help is much appreciated !!!

Comment: It would be nice if you would give us the Input and the expected output.

Comment: My file is something like below:
Pure delay path #308 ,
   0.003  0.003  0.032  0.003  (F) 0.003 af mclk    
   0.019  0.022  0.006  0.001  (F) 0.022 af mclk  
END OF PATH
Pure delay path #309,
   0.003  0.003  0.032  0.003  (F) 0.003 af mclk    
   0.019  0.022  0.006  0.001  (F) 0.022 af mclk  
END OF PATH

This is just for explanation. I will then need to add up all the first column in each of those mutli line matches and then print it along with the #id

Comment: Completely agree with @JFS31. Are all non-blank lines between the one matching `/Pure delay/I` and `/END OF PATH/I` considered to be a single match?

Comment: [Edit] your question, to show us a sample of your input and the corresponding desired output. **Don't** post in the comments

Comment: I'd use perl, FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

GNU **awk** solution, taking into account the following considerations:

- id might be showing up more than once. All values $1 will be summed.
- ids may not be in sequence, so you might find some "holes" in between.
- ids should be printed in order.

Script:

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0, /Pure delay path #([0-9]+)/, arr){
    id=arr[1]                                          # save id
    low=(low && low<id?low:id); high=(high<id?id:high) # save lowest/highest id
    next
}
id { a[id]=a[id]+$1 }                                  # sum up $1 for id
/END OF PATH/{ id=0 }
END{
    for (i=low; i<=high; i++)
        if (i in a)                                    # check if id is defined
            printf "id: #%s sum: %*.3f\n", i, length(a[i]), a[i]
}
```

Test data:

```
$ cat input.txt

Pure delay path #333,
0.003 0.003 0.032 0.003 (F) 0.003 af mclk
123.019 0.022 0.006 0.001 (F) 0.022 af mclk
END OF PATH

Pure delay path #309,
0.003 0.003 0.032 0.003 (F) 0.003 af mclk
0.019 0.022 0.006 0.001 (F) 0.022 af mclk
END OF PATH

Pure delay path #308 ,
0.003 0.003 0.032 0.003 (F) 0.003 af mclk
0.019 0.022 0.006 0.001 (F) 0.022 af mclk
END OF PATH
Pure delay path #309,
0.003 0.003 0.032 0.003 (F) 0.003 af mclk
123.019 0.022 0.006 0.001 (F) 0.022 af mclk
END OF PATH
```

Result:

```
 $ awk -f tst.awk input.txt
 id: #308 sum: 0.022
 id: #309 sum: 123.044
 id: #333 sum: 123.022
```

If you don't take the 3 considerations above into account, the script can be a lot simpler, like this:

```
$ cat tst2.awk
match($0, /Pure delay path #([0-9]+)/, arr){
    id=arr[1]
    next
}
id { a[id]=a[id]+$1 }
/END OF PATH/{
    printf "id: #%s sum: %*.3f\n", id, length(a[id]), a[id]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/Pure delay/I{:a;N;/END OF PATH/I!ba;s/match/replace/gp}' file
```

Gather up the required lines using the loop `:a;N;/match/!ba` then anything following can process the gathered up lines i.e. `s/match/replacement/gp`.

N.B. the final command should be a `p` or `P` command/flag otherwise nothing will be printed.

Comment: I like this one-liner quite a bit because it's about as clear as loops can get in sed.... but can you do arithmetic in sed?  OP needs to sum column 1 in each group.